# angular-error: unhandled exception: cannot find module @angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json

Tags: node.js, json, angular, helper

while I run (A perfectly fine project that worked for several people) on vs code I get this weird error that I can't understand :
[image]

from what I understand I don't have a specific file/package/folder? And I don't understand what I need to do? will love some help!

Comment: it seems you miss some packages, of course you've tried to install dependencies with `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

you guys I find the answer
All I need to do was run npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
and that it!